# Calculating the runtime of netLogo program

Tags: netlogo

How to calculate the time taken for  program to run . By running i mean, between the start and end of a typical go procedure?

I am implementing ant colony optimization algorithm to find the optimal path between a source and a network,and hence need to compute the time taken by the algorithm to run.I am confused about the approach to do it.

Comment: Use timers or a profiler, as described here: http://netlogo-users.18673.x6.nabble.com/profiling-optimisation-td4864833.html

Comment: Seems like a good question to me. Not sure why the close votes. I voted to reopen.